# Vtiger Report generation failed! Too many tables; MySQL can only use 61 tables in a join

Tags: mysql, crm, vtiger

Hello I am usign VTiger CRM version 5.1 and when a user i trying to generate Report called "Last Month activities" in the result area only following error is given:

Report generation failed!
Too many tables; MySQL can only use 61 tables in a join

The strangest thing about this behaviour is that under ADMIN user everything works as expected.

Can anyone advise me on this one?

Answer (score 2):

61 is a hard coded limit of tables used in a single query. No way around it short of changing MySQL's source code and recompiling. If you have this report working from one user, but not from other, that probably means VTiger CRM joins some more tables, when the user is not ADMIN.

Comment: Thanks. I found the same at MySQL forums. I was trying to reach someone who encountered similar problem.

Answer (score -1):

You can also increase the value of open tables.

> The cache of open tables is kept at a level of table_cache entries.
>   The default value is 64; this can be changed with the --table_cache
>   option to mysqld. Note that MySQL may temporarily open more tables
>   than this to execute queries.
>   http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_table_cache

Comment: Ï am afraid that this is not the case. As @Mchl wrote this would be about limit of joined tables.